# Jump to a div loaded using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

1. I have a page where I show list of products alphabetically. The products are loaded dynamically using ajax when the user starts scrolling
2. I have alphabet list on top of my page (A-Z), so when user clicks on any of the alphabet I need to scroll the page to the list of products starting with that alphabet
3. The function works fine if the div is loaded already i.e if user has scrolled and products starting with D are loaded and then user click on the Alphabet D on the top of page.
   If the list of products with the alphabet D is not loaded then I load all the products from A-D whichever are yet to be loaded but I am not able to scroll to the top of the div where list of products starting with D.

If any one has any pointers to solve the issue please help. 
Thanks in advance

Following is code snippet for my javascript code

```
    $('.jump').click(function () {
    var alphabet = $(this).text();
    var jumpToId = "#" + alphabet.toUpperCase();
    var targetAlphabetAscii = alphabet.charCodeAt(0);
    if (targetAlphabetAscii >= nextAlphabet)
    {
        var current = "";
        do {
            current = GetNextAlphabet();

       //This function loads the list of products and appends 
        //to a existing div on the page.
            GetProductData(current);

        } while (current != alphabet);
    }

    //The problem is here .. I dont get the offset because till the time the following 
    //code is executed the div with the selector jumpToId is not loaded.. 
    //so I get undefined error for .offset() method and cannot scroll

    var offset = $(jumpToId).offset();
    offset.left -= 20;
    offset.top -= 20;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset.top,
       scrollLeft: offset.left
     });


    });
```

The HTML anchors i.e the list of alphabets on top of page looks like this

`<ul>`

`<li class="circle"><a class="jump" href="#A">a</a></li>`

`<li class="circle"><a class="jump" href="#B">b</a></li>`

`<li class="circle"><a class="jump" href="#C">c</a></li>`

`<li class="circle"><a class="jump" href="#D">d</a></li>`

`</ul>`

Comment: Can you add empty divs to the initial page and just laid the contents?

Comment: Not clear exactly what problem is. Are you adding `jump` class links inside the ajax? Will need to delegate events if you are. If not is click handler firing?

Comment: @charlietfl : The jump class anchors are static and loaded when the page is loaded . Although the divs where we wanna scroll to are added using ajax

Comment: @SGD yes I can do that .. but what if the content is not loaded and the user is navigated to the empty div on the page. I want to load scroll after the content is loaded..
P.S. The list loads dynamically on mouse scroll

Comment: You need to add the scrolling as a function to be executed as a callback to your `GetProductData()` function (which I am assuming is the one doing the ajax call) - in other words, it does not work as is because ajax call is made, the scrolling is attempted but the response from the ajax call has not inserted the new content (the one you need to scroll to) so it does not exist yet

Comment: @ochi is exactly right, ajax is asynchronous so the elements have to exist ( and be visible) for you to get their location and that only occurs within the callback

Comment: @charlietfl I know that the div is not loaded and I am trying to scroll.. that is wat I mentioned as comment in my code.  GetProductData() is the same function  called to load the next set of products using ajax,  when the user scrolls. If I put the scrolling in the callback, it will keep scrolling whenever new set is loaded after user scrolls manually , which is not what I want ..
Is there a way where I can wait checking if the div is loaded yet or not and then scroll if I find that the div has been loaded

Comment: You can add a flag to your function to distinguish between manual scrolling and click from a letter - just an idea

Comment: @ochi I also had same idea in mind.. Let me try will tell if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your scroll function as a callback of your `GetDataContent()` function. Something like:

```
//Define scrolling function
var doScrolling = function(current){    
    var offset = $(current).offset();
        offset.left -= 20;
        offset.top -= 20;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offset.top,
           scrollLeft: offset.left
         });
};// end scrolling function

// now define your fetch data function
var GetProductData = function(current, isManualLoad){
        $.ajax( "example.php" ).done(function() {
            // ... append your content
           ...
           if( ! isManualLoad ){
               // and scroll to it
               doScrolling( current );
           }
        });
};
```

**Updated:** added flag to callback based on comments of OP